# El diccionario de parámetros contiene una entrada NULL para el parámetro 'nombre de la variable' del tipo que no acepta valores NULL

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

mi pregunta es porque suele salirme este error , no pongo un codigo en concreto ya que suele salirme en diferentes partes del programa , a que se debe este error y por lo general como suele solucionarse ?

El diccionario de parámetros contiene una entrada NULL para el parámetro 'por ejemplo (IdSucursal)' del tipo que no acepta valores NULL

PD : soy novato

gracias de antemano

Comment: lee tu error, con tu ejemplo IdSucursal, significa que le estás mandando NULL, a un campo que no permite recibir NULL. depura tu aplicación y verifica que se esté asignando el dato antes de guardar o lo que estés haciendo.

Comment: pd: sin código no te podemos ayudar, es mera suposición.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: aqui pongo el codigo del cual me salta el error

Comment: public ActionResult GenerarSap(int IdSucursal, DateTime DiaVenta, int IdCuadre)
        {
           
            var Usuario = Session["UserLogin"] as UserLogin;

          

            var ModelRespuestaGenerar = ConsultarSucursalService.SP_Generar_Registros_SapPos(IdSucursal, DiaVenta, Usuario.Usu_Nombre, IdCuadre);

           

            return RedirectToAction("DetalleSucursal", routeValues: new { IdCuadre = IdCuadre});
        }